# Get the result of MySQL CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe2, zeos

I am using Zeos lib to access and use MySQL tables. Now I want to create table myself. I can catch errors regarding CREATE TABLE command, but I can not get the success result.

For example if I use `IF NOT EXISTS` I don't know the tables created or not.

```pascal
DBQuery.SQL.Text:=
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbltest` ('+
        '  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,'+
        '  `Field` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,'+
        '  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),'+
    ') ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED AUTO_INCREMENT=1;';
DBQuery.ExecSQL;
```

Q: How do I know that tables created  successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A warning is created when your create table statement runs. If the table is created no warning will be generated, if it already exists it will fire a warning.  Check that after the query with:

```
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

Or you can use the following:

```
select @@warning_count;
```

See here for full info
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-warnings.html

Comment: I used `SHOW WARNINGS` to get warnings list. There is code 1050 for `'Table' already exists` situation. So if there isn't any warning or exception then operation is successful?

Comment: @SamPro "SHOW WARNINGS displays information about the conditions resulting from execution of the most recent nondiagnostic statement in the current session.".  Test it in your mysql client, you will see select @@warning_count will return 0 when the create table succeeds, and non zero otherwise.